# Implementing Custom Lock Screen image

Tags: group-policy

I have a Domain running at the Windows Server 2008 functional level, which cannot be upgraded currently due to logistics reasons. I have a group of Student-access clients all running Windows Server 2012 and would like to implement a custom lock/login screen background image across them. I cannot seem to find anything that would let me aside from running custom software which I am adverse to do.

I have tried looking for registry edits, GPO's(which would be preferrable), Group Policy Preferences and have found nothing that would permit this, I do know if I my Domain was running Windows Server 2012 there is a GPO built just for this but do not have access to that. Is there any way I can achieve this using no 3rd party software and/or preferably through Group Policy?

Answer (score 0):

I think this link answers what you are looking for. Hope it does.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2787100/en-us

Comment: Appears to be for Windows 8/2012.

Comment: In **the post **it said clients all running server 2012.

Comment: If it's Windows 7 clients , then I'd reference this link: http://www.howtogeek.com/112110/how-to-set-a-custom-logon-screen-background-on-windows-7/.  I use the information from this link and create a group policy that creates those registry keys/values. Make sure to filter the group policy object only to the group you'd like it to apply too

Comment: That update can only be applied to a Domain with Functional Level 2012 R1 or R2, but not 2008, and the other link on Howtogeek is how I set up our windows 7 client machines, but it doesnt apply to Server machines